# Add text to message box output

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to include a string in a single `MsgBox` format.

My code is

```
MsgBox Format((Timer - starttime) / 86400, "hh:mm:sss")
```

It will give me how long my code takes to execute.

When I enter a text in front of the "hh:mm:sss", it gives me a gibberish output.

Comment: `But when i tried to enter a text in front of the hhmmsss` What do you mean by this?

Comment: Have you tried this syntax, `Msgbox "My text" & Format ((timer- starttime) /86400 , "hh:mm:sss")`?

Answer (score 1):

Typical structure of `MsgBox` is

```
MsgBox "Text", (controls like vbInformation), "Title" etc.
```

For example

```
MsgBox "Some body of msgbox" & vbCrLf & "Second line of body", _
vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "title of msgbox"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any problems unless you havent asigned "starttime" ? Code works perfect and result is showing fine as formated.

```
Sub ine()
    starttime = Timer
    MsgBox Format((Timer - starttime) / 86400, "hh:mm:sss")
End Sub
```